# JavaScript return a JSON with a function name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm learning AngularJS, and someone wrote this code:

```
.factory('cribs',function(){
    var data = [{
        name: "jack",
        last: 'doe'
    },{
        name: 'hazel',
        last: 'man'
    }
    ];

    function getcrib(){
        return data;
    }
    return{
        getcrib: getcrib // what the heck does this mean?
    }
})
```

I'm baffled with the return line... he returned an object of `getcrib` with a function that returns the data? Does the `getcrib` at the beginning need to be the same exact case?

Comment: The semicolon is wrong, but yes, `getcrib` is a reference to the function declared in the lines above. The property name `getcrib` only matters to the user of the factory.

Comment: oh yes semi colon is wrong. could nt he just return the function itself instead of that? is this line of code similar? `var t = function getcrib(){ ..} return t` as such?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this tiny example, but when things get more complicated, by having a single place where you can see: 'return {usefulFunction: usefulFunction, anotherUsefulFunction: anotherUsefulFunction, ..., etc. }', it helps a person get a quick look at what gets 'exported' by the factory without having to wade through a ton of function declarations.

Comment: Yes, returning a function directly instead of returning an object with a single method is often a good idea, however you loose the method name which might or might not be significant. You'll want to ask the author of the code why he chose this approach, we cannot know.

Comment: Thank you very much guys!!! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the four codes below does the same thing. Hope you have a better understanding on function declarations. :)

**Code 1:**

```
.factory('cribs',function(){
    var data = 3.142;
    function getcrib(){
        return data;
    }
    return{
        getcrib: getcrib 
    }
})
//console.log(cribs.getcrib()) outputs 3.142
```

> Explanation:
>
> 1. An object is returned.
> 2. This object has a property of `getcrib`, which reference the function whose name is also `getcrib`.

**Code 2:**

```
.factory('cribs', function() {
  var data = 3.142;
  return {
    getcrib: function() {
      return data;
    }
  }
})
//console.log(cribs.getcrib()) outputs 3.142
```

> Explanation:
>
> 1. An object is returned.
> 2. This object has a property of `getcrib`, which reference an anonymous function. (anonymous is a function without a name)

**Code 3:**

```
.factory('cribs',function(){
    var data = 3.142;
    function GET_PI_VALUE(){
        return data;
    }
    return{
        getcrib: GET_PI_VALUE
    }
})
//console.log(cribs.getcrib()) outputs 3.142
```

> Explanation:
>
> 1. An object is returned.
> 2. This object has a property of `getcrib`, which reference a function whose name is called `GET_PI_VALUE`. This is the same case as code 1

**Code 4:**

```
.factory('cribs', function() {
  var data = 3.142;
  return {
    getcrib: function GET_PI_VALUE() {
      return data;
    }
  }
})
//console.log(cribs.getcrib()) outputs 3.142
```

> Explanation:
>
> 1. An object is returned.
> 2. This object has a property of `getcrib`, which reference a function whose name is called `GET_PI_VALUE`. This is the same case as code 3.

**Code 5**

```
.factory('cribs', function() {
  var data = 3.142;
  return {
    getcrib: function GET_PI_VALUE() {
      return data;
    }
  }
})
//console.log(cribs.GET_PI_VALUE()) gives an error, complaining GET_PI_VALUE is not a function.
```

> Explanation:
>
> 1. An object is returned.
> 2. This object has a property of `getcrib`
> 3. `GET_PI_VALUE` is totally shadowed, hence error. The function of `GET_PI_VALUE` itself was **NOT** returned, only the reference(via getcribs) is returned.

Comment: wow thank you very much! I get confused with returning a function without the bracket and with a bracket. Im really slow at this but this really helps! Thank you for a thorough explanation of a noob javascripter :D

Comment: blame those javascript inventors who come up with this confusing convention! :P

Comment: And javascript not having a proper `class` name, I thought he was returning an object instead of a function, I was also learning about `prototype.constructor = ObjectNameOrfunctionName;`and combined with what I saw . just confuses me. Oh a follow up question, if factory is being returned wouldnt the function inside be automatically be callable as well? or should he go something like `this.function getcrib(){ .. }`?

Comment: @Chopnut What a good follow up. No, the function insides are **NOT** callable. They are shadowed.  You can only access what is returned. This is sort of a nice encapsulation in away. See my edit on Code 5

Comment: Wow awesome! I wouldnt have known that! Because any start up tutorial doesnt tell you that!Cause he didnt explain why he had to return a function, I was like thats weird.. Man youre a life saver! Thats it for now =) Super thanks! Done deal.

Comment: Perhaps there should be another example that EXPLICITLY shows that it's returning an object with a method `getcrib`. Maybe `var theObject = {}; theObject.getcrib = function () {}; return theObject`